# Unknown btc transaction

Tags: transactions, bitcoin-core, blockchain, unconfirmed-transactions

Could someone please explain what is this second transaction from the wallet 34UuFs8BtnbeJtdM9p4NBCHiP8MaD4f86n ?
https://www.blockchain.com/btc/address/34UuFs8BtnbeJtdM9p4NBCHiP8MaD4f86n?filter=6

I didn't make the transaction with hash c454a01256ba3a4831f0bd02ada0a6bddb6d4c92d9b93af22938daf82b3d23dc

and it is not reflected in my wallet, also, it has not decreased my balance.
So, what can it be ?

Comment: Does the wallet address belong to an online exchange such as Coinbase, Binance, etc?  If this is the case, these type of wallets will usually move around the funds in wallets but will still allow you to spend from a separate address based on the documented amount you have in their proprietary database.

Answer (score 2):

it's clear that you have custodial wallet such as coinbase or localbitcoins so, they are controlling your wallet, and you don't own your wallet master key.

I suggest you use Bitcoin-core or electrum since they give you full access to your bitcoins and nobody ever has access to your wallet.